# How can I increment a counter in an if statement

Tags: html, jquery, css, dom

I am currently coding a mini Pokémon game using HTML, CSS, and jQuery. The game is about finding hidden Pokémon and whenever I hover over them they have to be counted.

I want to create a counter with an `if` statement to count whenever I hover over them and logging in to the console, but the counter does not want to increment at all. I have tried putting the `if` statement inside and outside of `$(document).ready(), but it just will not increment at all

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("jQuery added and ready");

  $(".block").css("opacity", "0");
  $(".results").hide();

  $("div").hasClass(".extraClass");

  $(".poke-1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });

  $(".poke-1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  });

  $(".poke-2").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });

  $(".poke-2").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  });

  $(".poke-3").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });

  $(".poke-3").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  });

  $(".poke-4").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });

  $(".poke-4").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  });
})

var counter = 0;

if ($(".poke-1").mouseenter()) {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
} else if ($(".poke-2").mouseenter()) {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
} else if ($(".poke-3").mouseenter()) {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
}

if (counter > 4) {

  $(".results").slideDown();
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.hidden-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.block {
  padding: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  /* RE-ADD THE OPACITY */
  /* opacity: 0; */
}

.block img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 60px;
}

.block p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.block:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #E84E4A;
  color: #101010;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: rgba(66, 34, 34, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
  /* RE-ADD THE DISPLAY NONE
*/
  /* display: none; */
}

.results h5 {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <h1 class="title">Pokémon Game</h1>
    <h5>Find the hidden Pokémon</h5>
    <img src="img/pokeball.png" alt="pokeball logo" width="80" />
  </div>

  <div class="hidden-blocks">
    <div class="block poke-1">
      <img src="img/meowth.png">
      <h2>Meowth</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="block poke-2">
      <img src="img/bullbasaur.png">
      <h2>Bullbasaur</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="block poke-3">
      <img src="img/pikachu.png">
      <h2>Pikachu</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="block poke-3">
      <img src="img/squirtle.png">
      <h2>Squirtle</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <img src="img/gotcha.png" alt="victory" width="70">
    <h1>You Caught 'Em All!</h1>
    <h5>Move your pointer over here to restart</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that you're attempting to use an event handler in an `if` statement. This is not valid Javascript. You need to hook some logic to the event handler and execute it whenever the event runs; exactly as you already do in the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Also note that there's a couple of other issues in your code. Firstly, set the `opacity` and `display` states of your elements in CSS, not JS. This is to avoid the [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) when the page first loads.

Secondly, you can remove the repetition in your JS code by using the same `.poke` class on the elements instead of incremental `.poke-X`. This allows you to use a single event handler for all elements, instead of one each. This technique is known as 'Don't Repeat Yourself', or 'DRY'.

Lastly you didn't set the returned value from `hasClass()` to a variable, so that line of code served no purpose and can be removed.

With all that said, try this working example:

```js
let counter = 0;  

jQuery($ => {
  $(".poke").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    counter++;
    checkCounter();
  });

  $(".poke").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  });
})

let checkCounter = () => {
  if (counter > 4)
    $(".results").slideDown();
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.hidden-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.block {
  padding: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.block img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 60px;
}

.block p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.block:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #E84E4A;
  color: #101010;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: rgba(66, 34, 34, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
  display: none;
}

.results h5 {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <h1 class="title">Pokémon Game</h1>
    <h5>Find the hidden Pokémon</h5>
    <img src="img/pokeball.png" alt="pokeball logo" width="80" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-blocks">
    <div class="block poke">
      <img src="img/meowth.png">
      <h2>Meowth</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block poke">
      <img src="img/bullbasaur.png">
      <h2>Bullbasaur</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block poke">
      <img src="img/pikachu.png">
      <h2>Pikachu</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block poke">
      <img src="img/squirtle.png">
      <h2>Squirtle</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <img src="img/gotcha.png" alt="victory" width="70">
    <h1>You Caught 'Em All!</h1>
    <h5>Move your pointer over here to restart</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, sorry I'm still a university student and I'm still learning jQuery / JS and I do not know what the following code means:

$($ => {
        $(".poke").mouseenter(function() {
          $(this).css("opacity", "1");
          counter++;
          checkCounter();
        });
      
        $(".poke").mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).css("opacity", "0");
        });
      })
      
      let checkCounter = () => {
        if (counter > 4)
          $(".results").slideDown();
    }

    console.log(counter);

})

Comment: Also, what does let mean and =>, if you don't mind explaining it to me.

Comment: Sure, MDN is a great resource for understanding Javascript. See their articles on the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)